# specify different --mode values using GNU tar

Tags: permissions, tar

I am trying to use GNU `tar` to create a tarball from a directory stored on a network drive. This network drive defaults the mode of everything stored on it to `0700` (`-rwx------`) and cannot be changed prior to the tarball creation.

I had used this command to change the permissions of my files stored inside the tarball:

```
tar -c --mode=0644 -f project.tar ./project/
```

The issue is that everything in the tarball has its permissions changed to `0644` (`-rw-r--r--`). There are no executables in this `./project/` directory, so `0644` for all **files** is okay, but **directories** end up inheriting `0644` as well. Upon extraction on another system, directories cannot be entered until the execute bit is added.

Is it possible to instruct GNU `tar` to change the modes of all **files** to `0644` and change the modes of all **directories** to `0755`? Almost like `-type f` and `-type d` in the `find` command.

OS is version Debian 11 Bullseye, GNU `tar` is version 1.34.

Comment: In past, for distribution of packages, we copied all sources in a new directory, we set up the permissions (ev. updating times, manifests, versions), and we did a tarball from there. You have more flexibility (e.g. if you have scripts which should have executable bit, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [GNU `tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/), you can do:

```
tar --mode a=r,u+w,a+X -cf file.tar directory
```

Which would get you `rwxr-xr-x` for files of type directory, and `rw-r--r--` for every other type (including symlinks, even to directories). That's built as:

- `a=r`: resets permissions to `r--r--r--`
- `u+w`: adds `w` to `u`ser, so `rw-r--r--`
- `a+X`: adds `x` to `a`ll, but only on files of type directory so  `rwxr-xr-x` for directories and `rw-r--r--` for any other type of file.

To get  full flexibility, you can use [`star`](https://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html):

```
star cf file.tar -find directory \
     -type d -chmod 755 \
  -o -type l -chmod 777 \
  -o         -chmod 644
```

Where we get `rwxr-xr-x` for files of type `d`irectory, `rwxrwxrwx` for files of type sym`l`ink, and `rw-r--r--` for any other type of file.

Or using the symbolic forms:

```
star cf file.tar -find directory \
     -type d -chmod a=rx,u+w \
  -o -type l -chmod a=rwx \
  -o         -chmod a=r,u+w
```

Comment: Does permissions for sym-link matter. My system sets all symlinks to 777.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, it matters on some such as macos, on most others it doesn't matter and on many, you can't even change it to anything other than `rwxrwxrwx`

Comment: Do you know why. I think it changed, as I remember seeing other modes. I am wondering if it was because the mode was useless, AND we needed the bits to specify other file types.

Answer (score 3):

You can use relative [permissions like with chmod](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Symbolic-Modes.html), not just a fixed mode with `--mode`. Check the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/override.html#index-mode), not just the man page.

You can use use `a+r` to grant everyone read permission and [`a+X`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Conditional-Executability.html) to grant execution permission if it was present anywhere.

```
tar -c --mode=a+rX …
```

However, if the filesystem makes all files executable, that will result in having all files executable in the archive. I don't think there's a way to adjust files differently with GNU tar. (Actually, [no there is: `+X` also makes directories executable if they're readable, so `a=r,u+w,a+X` works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/755443).)

Pax doesn't have any way to adjust permissions at all.

I think the simplest approach is to use [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/) to create a view of the filesystem with different metadata. This is a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem, so it can be installed and used without administrator privileges as long as your system has FUSE itself installed. Bindfs offers more flexibility than GNU tar's `--mode`. Another benefit is that it can used with programs that don't have something similar to `tar --mode`. You can use the [`--perms` option](https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html#sect3) to [change permissions](https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html#sect13):

```
mkdir -p views/project
bindfs --no-allow-other -p a+rD project views/project
tar -C views -cf project.tar project
fusermount -u views/project
rmdir views/project
```

Python has a [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) module which makes it relatively convenient to write code. I think it supports iterative archiving so you wouldn't need to store the whole archive in memory at once. But you'd still have to write quite a bit of code.

Comment: oh bindfs is a good idea! I'm still a bit confused that nobody wrote a "edit these fixed fields in tar file headers" tool that I'm aware of.

Comment: While it might be somewhat overkill, `bindfs -p 'u=rwD,go=rD' /home/user/Documents/projects /mnt/tarsrc/projects` appears, on the surface, to achieve exactly what I'm looking for when using it as a source for `tar`. I won't accept the answer for now, however, since it is more of a workaround than a direct, `tar`-only solution. I appreciate this nonetheless.

Comment: `--mode=a+rX` would work if the default permissions of the network share weren't already set to assume every file is executable.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was wondering about a direct tarball editing utility also, as I have a number of already-made tarballs with directories lacking execute bits. I'm sure a hex editor tweak might work but something less human-error-prone would be nice.

Comment: @leetbacoon note that Gilles' approach wasn't primarily the bindfs approach, but simply adding file by file with its individual permissions set correctly!

Comment: for example, (assuming this won't be so many files it exceeds your command line maximum), `tar -cf archive.tar --no-recursion --mode 0755 **/*` in `zsh` would first store all directories (in bottom-up order), then `tar -rf archive.tar --mode 0644 **/*(^/Odon)` would append all files.

Comment: @leetbacoon My bad, I hadn't noticed that you do need to treat regular files differently from directories. Then bindfs is my recommended solution.

Comment: remove `x` before adding `X`. to get `x` only on directories.

Answer (score 1):

You could work around `tar`'s inability to change attributes according to rules by – not using `tar`.

`mksquashfs` has a mini-language for *actions* built in, which can applied to archive entries as they come along, according to some filtering rules; the whole thing is documented [here](https://github.com/plougher/squashfs-tools/blob/master/ACTIONS-README). It's quite simple: the syntax is `action@condition`, so for us:

```
mksquashfs ./project/ project.squashfs -no-strip -action 'chmod(0755)@type(d)' -action 'chmod(644)@type(f)'
```

will make all directory entries have 0755 permissions, and all files have `0644` permisions. You might have fifos, sockets, symlinks in your folder, so maybe instead of "directories" and "files", the better categorization would be "directories" and "everything not a directory"; then, throw in some compression that's probably faster than your network is, for free:

```
mksquashfs ./project/ project.squashfs \
          -no-strip \
          -action 'chmod(0755)@type(d)' \
          -action 'chmod(644)@!type(d)' \
          -comp zstd -Xcompression-level 10
```

Usage of this archive:

1. can be extracted using `unsquashfs project.squashfs` (and probably your favorite graphical archive manager, as well)
2. (on Linux) can be mounted readonly (as root) using `mount -o loop gr-ieee802-11.squash /home/marcus/mnt/`
3. (on Linux) can be mounted readonly by any user using a modern desktop environment: `udisksctl loop-setup -f project.squashfs` (and if that doesn't automount, `udisksctl mount -b` or clicking on the newly appeared drive in your file manager.

Comment: This sounds very interesting & could be great for future/personal archives, but in my particular case, POSIX-compliant tarballs are necessary due to them being simple, time-proven and, well, POSIX compliant (my `tar` command really uses `--posix`, btw, but this option was omitted from my Q for brevity). I'm not discrediting squashfs in any way; I see it in Linux distros a lot and it seems nice. From my research it doesn't appear POSIX-compliant which is unfortunately a dealbreaker (please tell me if I'm wrong). Thank you for your answer, I'm sure to use it in the future! :)

Comment: @leetbacoon no need to be so sorry about it :) I can understand that if the requirement is "make a POSIX tar", then you need a POSIX tar :) (you could convert a squashfs archive through `sqfs2tar` to a tar, or by just mounting it and tar'ing the directory, but that's quite a convoluted approach :). (tar being time-proven, hm yes, but how many million devices boot from a tar file rather than a squashfs root image? I'd argue the format "tar" isn't really *good*, it just *is there*.)